# How do you ignore the rest of an input line and resume starting from the next input line?

Tags: c

I just started learning C. How do you ignore the rest of an input line and resume on the next input line? For example:

Input:

```
123456789123456789
hello how are you
```

Output:

```
123456
hello h
```

Comment: looks more like this: input being: "12345" and next line being "how are you "and the outputs: "123" ignores the rest and resumes on the next inputted line "how are you"

Comment: You are not defining what the criterion for ignoring the inputs is.

Comment: By getting a whole line at a time with `fgets()`. Then you can output what you like from what you got, and you don't have to ignore anything.

Answer (score 1):

Short answer is you can't.
When working with input, especially command line and or program input.
You have to process it, argument by argument, line by line.

I would suggest that you use delimiters ("$","\n","&") to better manage your input.

Comment: Don't forget to up vote my answer. I'm new here and learning just like you. As you get used to the way that things work on this website, people might make suggestions to you on how to improve your use of it.

Answer (score 1):

I'm really not sure what's your question, but do you mean something like this?

```
scanf("%6s%*[^\n]", string);
scanf("%*c%6s", string + 6);
```